# how do I add to to contents of a td with jquery?

Tags: jquery, string, html-table

Im trying to get the text in a td with an id of "warningLabel", add to the text, then put the new text in the td.

I tried:

`$('#warningLabel').html($('#warningLabel').html()+ "Please enter a date.\n");`

This doesnt work but it doesnt raise any errors in firebug either.

If it matters, "warningLabel" may have no text in it to begin with.

How should i be doing this?

**Update**

---

**The td in question starts out hidden**

More of my code:

```
$(function(){   

function fieldsEntered(){
var check = true;
if($('#date').val()==""){
    $('#warningLabel').html($('#warningLabel').html()+ "Please enter a date.\n");
    check = false;
}
if($('#warningLabel').html()!=""){
    $('#warningLabel').show();
}


 return check;

}

});
```

Comment: Where you have this code, showing html / javascript could help us finding the problem.

Comment: Is #warningLabel visible otherwisE?

Comment: I wouldn't describe that as the _best_ way to do it, but it should work assuming that code is in a document ready handler and/or in a script block that appears after the element in question, and that there is only one element with that id. Can you provide a demo at http://jsfiddle.net where it doesn't work?

Comment: Your example works for me. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NVZP/)

Comment: So (regarding your update) `fieldsEntered()` is never called?

Comment: nnnnnnn yes its called, and it is getting called so that didnt seem relavent sorry. IT seems this might have something to do with the td not being visible when the function is called as others have shown that it does work otherwise

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the element is hidden at the time. `.html()` should still work.

Comment: yeah, I see that I must have had something else wrong somewhere, .append() is still a better route and I have it going now, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you heard of [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)?

Just try,

```
$('#warningLabel').append("Please enter a date.<br>");
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7NVZP/1/)** showing how it works.

Also try showing the td after you add content to your warningLabel.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten about `.append()` this worked. Thank you.

Comment: no I edited == to != as it was a typo here and not reflective of my actual code.